# How to efficiently parallelize numpy nested for loop

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, conv-neural-network

I have in my code 3 nested `for` loops that make a calculation on an array, based on the loops indices (Not very important to note, but the logic is of CNN Max Pooling layer error calculation and CNN Convolutional layer weight update).

Generally in my code, I used `cupy` to easily make `numpy` operations run on GPU, and it indeed reduced calculation times greatly.

However, here I understand that the nested loops must run on CPU, leaving the calculation itself run on GPU (which comes with overhead of copying the arrays), causing terrible slowness, being even slower than regular CPU calculation.

I know that threading wouldn't really help because of the `GIL`

So I tried `multiprocessing` and `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` but I guess because both have the overhead of creating a new process, the performance is still worse than the regular case.

The calculations in each iteration are completely independent of other iterations, each time filling one cell in the numpy matrix, so logically there must be a way to do it parallely.

Is there an easy way to do it in python? (I prefer not to start studying CUDA and implement a whole kernel on my own...)

That's the code I want to parallelize (not necessarily with GPU, whatever makes the best performance).

```
"""
Array shapes are:
self.feeded_values: (32, 16, 16)
prev_layer_error: (32, 8, 8)
"""
def calculate_errors(self, prev_layer_error: np.array):
    result = np.zeros(self.input_shape)  # Shape of (32, 16, 16)
    for feature_map_index, feature_map in enumerate(self.feeded_values):
        for i in range(prev_layer_error[feature_map_index].shape[0]):
            for j in range(prev_layer_error[feature_map_index].shape[1]):
                pool = np.array(feature_map[i * 2:i * 2 + 2, j * 2:j * 2 + 2])
                max_i, max_j = np.unravel_index(pool.argmax(), pool.shape)
                result[feature_map_index][i * 2 + max_i][j * 2 + max_j] += prev_layer_error[feature_map_index][i][j]

    return result


"""
Array shapes are:
self.next_weights: (16, 32, 3, 3)
self.feeded_values: (16, 16, 16)
prev_error: (32, 16, 16)
"""
def update_weights(self, prev_error):
    for i in range(self.output_shape[0]): # Shape is (32, 16, 16)
        x = np.pad(prev_error[i], ((1, 1), (1, 1)), mode='constant')
        for j in range(self.input_shape[0]): # Shape is (16, 16, 16)
            deltas = np.zeros((3, 3))
            w = self.next_weights[j][i]
            values = ActivationFunction.ReLU.f(self.feeded_values[j])

            deltas[0][0] += np.sum(values * x[:-2, :-2])  # bottom right
            deltas[0][1] += np.sum(values * x[:-2, 1:-1])  # bottom
            deltas[0][2] += np.sum(values * x[:-2, 2:])  # bottom left

            deltas[1][0] += np.sum(values * x[1:-1, :-2])  # right
            deltas[1][1] += np.sum(values * prev_error[i])  # center
            deltas[1][2] += np.sum(values * x[1:-1, 2:])  # left

            deltas[2][0] += np.sum(values * x[2:, :-2])  # top right
            deltas[2][1] += np.sum(values * x[2:, 1:-1])  # top
            deltas[2][2] += np.sum(values * x[2:, 2:])

            w += deltas
```

Comment: You may find that threading is enough to parallelize your code, because numpy [often releases the GIL during long calculations](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Multithreading.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can safely do it in Numba (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html) where it suffices to decorate your method with @njit and replace `range` with `prange`:

```
@njit(parallel=True)
def update_weights(self, prev_error):
    for i in prange(self.output_shape[0]):
        x = np.pad(prev_error[i], ((1, 1), (1, 1)), mode='constant')
        for j in prange(self.input_shape[0]):
            deltas = np.zeros((3, 3))
            ...
```

`prange` will execute a `for` loop in parallel. The clever thing is that if two nested `prange` would lead to elevate computational burden, one or both will be treated as `range` and executed sequentially behind the scene.

Caution, however, must be taken on the supported operations (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#supported-operations) and supported Numpy ufuncs (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html#supported-ufuncs). For example, it seems that your function `np.pad` is not supported. Can you implement it differently?